# RTMP Library .Net Broccoli

Tags: rtmp

I'm using RTMP .Net Client Library by Broccoli Products to save live streaming radio.
I try their example FileDump.cs [click here to view code](http://www.broccoliproducts.com/softnotebook/rtmpclient/FileDump.cs) with those data :

```
RtmpServer  77.67.21.79
RtmpPort  RtmpClient.DefaultRtmpPort
RtmpApp   live/
RtmpTcUrl  rtmp://cp154821.live.edgefcs.net/live/
RtmpStreamName  Radio24Audio@69140
```

I get this error :

```
!!! Failed to play stream.  Stream not found.  Server response follows:  OBJECT
Children=5 STRING level="error", STRING code="NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound", ST
RING description="Failed to play Radio24Audio@69140; stream not found.", STRING
details="Radio24Audio@69140", STRING clientid="pAAnAEBA"
```

But if i use RTMPDump program with same data it is ok